# How to prevent EditText from being cleared after choosing a photo

Tags: android, android-image

i created a function that allows people to choose image from their gallery. While the function works, i realized that after choosing the image, the edit text in that activity is cleared. Is there a way to prevent the text from being cleared? Have tried the onSaveInstanceState but it did not work.

These are code snippets for choosing the photo

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private void selectPhoto() {
        if (getIntent().getExtras()!= null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("SelectImage")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null && data.getClipData() != null) {
                int totalItems = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    imageNameList.add(imageUri);

                }
            } else if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                imageNameList.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Picture of Activity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to got it to work by using sharedPreferences and changing my onPause() and onResume() methods and adding a line in my onCreate() method.

Initialized an additional field in my activity class:

```
SharedPreferences pref;
```

Line added for onCreate():

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

my onResume() and onPause() method. Made it generic so others can refer

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (pref.getString("KEY_OF_STRING", "") != null) {
        YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.setText(pref.getString("KEY_OF_STRING", ""));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("KEY_OF_STRING", "STRING_TO_STORE");
        editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your activity inside the manifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode=”singleTop”
```

So, your manifest should look something like this:

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
package="com.package.example"  
android:versionCode="1"  
android:versionName="1.0" >  

<application  
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
    android:label="@string/app_name"  
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
    <!-- This is the activity for which you want this behaviour-->
    <activity  
        android:name=".MainActivity"  
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:launchMode=”singleTop”>
    </activity>  
</application>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. After changing the manifest file, clicking on the floating action button with the camera icon does not bring up the file chooser

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the input text with a static variable and try setting the text of the EDitText to it if the variable isnt empty.

`...
private String savedEditTextText = "";
...
@Override public void onCreate(SavedInstanceState savedInstanceState) {
...
if (!savedEditTextText.isEmpty())
  mEditText.setText(savedTextViewText);
...
}`

Comment: Hi, i have tried this. If i use a static string variable, it allows the text to be saved. However, when i edit other entries, the static string variable will replace what is inside the edit text originally